# Are Heroku URLs dependable?

Tags: heroku

I just deployed my first app to Heroku. I'm on the free tier, and the app is a little demo of a Ruby gem.

Running `heroku open` sends me to a URL that looks something like `http://armored-magpie-3920.herokuapp.com`.

- Is this URL dependable, meaning I can link to it and expect it not to change?
- If not, is the IP dependable, so that I could register a domain name and point it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The URL is dependable as long as you don't change the name of the application. The pattern is $app_name.herokuapp.com. So if you ran `heroku apps:rename new-hotness-app-12` the new URL would be `http://new-hotness-app-12.herokuapp.com`.
2. No, the IP is not dependable (even if it might seem that way). The proper way to point a custom domain to a Heroku application is to use a CNAME on the custom domain the points to the herokuapp.com URL or to use a DNS provider that supports CNAME records at the apex ([see here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains)). See the Heroku [documentation re: custom domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) for more information.

Comment: The name in the URL isn't my app name; it is either random or the name of one of their servers I guess?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. When I mean app name, I mean the Heroku name of the application. In your case this is the randomly generated name 'armored-magpie-3920'. You can change "heroku name" of the application as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

People who run applications on Heroku typically register their own domain names and then configure the Heroku application to be available at that domain name.

Every Heroku application is, in the interim, available at a subdomain of *.herokuapp.com so that authors can develop the application before they have registered the domain name of their dreams or configured the application to be available at that domain.

As long as you do not rename your application, the URL is dependable. However, renaming your application within Heroku, while keeping the same custom domain name that you register, is a fully supported and expected part of the platform.

The IP address is never dependable. Heroku explicitly warns authors not to depend on the IP address in any way. In fact, Heroku's routing layer has many IP addresses, and those IP addresses are for the whole routing layer, not for any application in particular. You are supposed to use domain names alone.